# How to pass the image path in GimpFU

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

How can I pass a parameter in GimpFU python?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *
import traceback
import sys


def upload_image(img, layer, dir):
    # Actual plug-in code will go here
    try:
        open('/tmp/upload.txt', 'w+').write('img:\n')
    except:
        open('/tmp/upload_error.txt', 'w+').write(traceback.format_exc())
        open('/tmp/upload_error.txt', 'a').write(sys.exc_info()[0])

    return


register(
    "Uploader",
    "Boo",
    "Far",
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "2014",
    "<Image>/File/Upload",
  "*", 
[],
[],
    upload_image)
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chek any other python-fu plug-in - 
the first list on the parameters list is where you specify the input parameters.
Each item on the list is a tuple of a minimum of 4 elements:
The paramter type (for example, PF_FILE, or PF_STRING, a string with the parameter name,
a string with the textual description of the parameter (used as label and tooltip),
and a default value.).

PF_FILE however had been broken for a while, and will work again on GIMP 2.8.12 - in other versions, you can't use PF_FILE to select a not-yet exiting filename.

Comment: do you have any idea if it's possible to add a dropdown menu?

Comment: You can use PF_OPTIONS, IIRC, it starts as radio buttons, but when you have more than a few options, it becomes a drop-down.

Comment: no - that does not work and tbh there is no PF_OPTIONS at least not in the documentation

Comment: Sorry - it is PF_OPTION, without any magic - just a drop down list.